# How to call a object defined function from the a different function in the same object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, google-maps-api-3

I am making custom object with javascript for small personal project to be used with tablets mostly (but with laptops as well). The object deals with google maps, gps tracking as well as other procedures. Inside the object I have defined couple function to be called from outside of object (`enableGps, disableGps`). Inside enableGps I start tracking while using outside error_handler and inside object function (`this.handleGps`) to handle gps data (latitude, longtitude, accuracy, etc). In `this.handleGps` I try to call `this.updateGpsMarker` function to update actual marker on the map but exception is thrown.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method
>   'updateGpsMarker'

How can I call `this.updateGpsMarker` from `this.handleGps`? Please note I need `this.updateGpsMarker` to be available as a function to be called from outside (long explanation)
I will throw code just to make it more clear what I am trying to do.

```
function RouteAssistant(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
{
    // Google mapping and geocoding
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    this.geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.gpsMarker = null;

    this.updateGpsMarker = function(lat, lon)
    {
        console.log("Updating GPS marker");
        if (this.gpsMarker == null)
        {
            console.log("GPS Marker not created. Creating GPS marker at " + lat + "," + lon);
            this.gpsMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
                map: this.map,
                title: "I am here!"
            });
            this.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon));
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("GPS Marker created. Updating GPS marker to " + lat + "," + lon);
            this.gpsMarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon));
        }
    }

    // GPS and tracking
    this.gpsProcess = null;
    this.enableGps = function (handle_errors)
    {
        if (this.gpsProcess == null) {
            console.log("Enabling GPS");
            this.gpsProcess = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.handleGps, handle_errors);
        }
    };
    this.disableGps = function()
    {
        if (this.gpsProcess != null)
        {
            console.log("Disabling GPS");
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.gpsProcess);
            this.gpsProcess = null;
        }
    };
    this.handleGps = function(position)
    {
        this.updateGpsMarker(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only way I could make this work is by defining external (out of object) updateGpsMarker function and passing RouteAssistant object to it. This is my last resort

Comment: how exactly are you calling the updateMarker function ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can create a clean object using something like the revealing modulo pattern and put all your functions in. Something like

```
 var routeAssistant = function(mapCanvas, mapOptions) {

     var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions).
     updateGpsMarker = function(lat, long) {
         //You can directly access 'map' here.
     };
     return {
      updateGpsMarker : updateGpsMarker
     }; 
 };
```

You can then use this by doing

```
  var myObject = new routeAssistant(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  myObject.updateGpsMarker(latitude,longtitude);
```